# AJAX request time over

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, get

I did ajax get request on php file that takes temperature data via snmp and give back a json array of data.

Now for every location I'm trying to generate only once the divs and then only update the values.

Treid to do on the first ajax request to generate the divs with the values inside already to an array and then display them but they won't display in the specific div.

I can see in the console that the array is properly populated. But I can't make it display all the elements in the div with id=data. Tried html(), append(), text() and nothing works.

How should I modify the code so the request won't take that much time?

I'm thinking of creating containers for every location temperature once with the first ajax request and then using setIntervals only getting the value and updating it so I guess it won't take that much time on the request and I will avoid page flickering cause only the numbers will change but how can I achieve that?

I don't want to reload the page.

```
      $(document).ready(function(){

          var tr_str = [];
          var menu_list = [];

          $.ajax({
              url: 'getData.php',
              type: 'get',
              dataType: 'JSON',
              success: function(response){
                  var len = response.length;
                  for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                      var location = response[i].location;
                      var temp_int = response[i].temp_int;
                      var temp = response[i].temp;
                      var hum = response[i].hum;
                      var dew = response[i].dew;

                      tr_str[i] = "<div id='locc" + i + "' class='location'>" +
                          "<span class='title'>" + location + "</span>" +
                          "<div class='temp'" + i + "><span>Temperatura: </span><span id='check'>" + temp + " &degC</span></div>" +
                          "<div><span>Względna wilgotność: </span><span>" + hum + " %RH</span></div>" +
                          "<div><span>Punkt rosy: </span><span>" + dew + " &degC</span></div>" +
                          "</div>";

                      menu_list[i] = "<label for='loc" + i + "'>" +
                          "<input type='checkbox' id='loc" + i + "' />" +
                          "<span class='css-checkbox'></span>" +
                          "<p>" + location + "</p>" +
                          "</label>";
                  }

              },

          });


          console.log(tr_str);
          console.log(menu_list);


            $("#data").html(tr_str[0]);

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <body>
    <div id="data" class="wrapper"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: You only add the html of `tr_str[0]` to `#data`. Is that intended? Also at the time you add it the content is not even there yet. Just move `$("#data").html(tr_str[0]);` straight after the finish of the for-loop in your `success` callback.

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. You have to insert the new html (or modify existing elements) from inside the success callback

Comment: @Lain Yes it was intended co check if I get back somethign but I did not get the result.

Comment: The php file gets the temperature data from 15 sensors via snmp, so how can I generate a separate div (column) for each sensor data using ajax request and not get the flicker of the page and to have the request faster than 10 to 15 seconds? Cause I will have like 50 sensors in the end. And I need to have it on the screen with refreshing every 10 seconds and checking if the temperature is not to big, cause when it gets over 25c i WANT IT TO SEND A WARNING.

Comment: Just do what @Lain wrote and append it inside the success callback after the for-loop.